# I Have Gradle problem to build apk in flutter [Could not resolve all files for configuration]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build

I have this flutter project and during debug build it does not have any problem and works fine but
in release build I have a gradle error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sentry_flutter:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sentry_flutter:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform lifecycle-process-2.2.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find lifecycle-process-2.2.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.2.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-process/2.2.0/lifecycle-process-2.2.0.aar
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-process/2.2.0/lifecycle-process-2.2.0.jar
```

this is my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
}
```

this is my repositories

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

i tried any jobs to resolve this problem but not working

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8238)